# 70’s Short story, found in a US or UK anthology about an old man that thinks the electricity in his house is talking

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story concerns an old man who lives alone in the country. He becomes convinced that the electricity that is crackling through the 'cables' of his home are talking - indeed they are planning something. I think he is found dead in the end - a case of 'knowing too much' perhaps. I thought it was Ray Bradbury but am pretty convinced it is a big name American sci-fi writer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is '[The man who made friends with electricity](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74494)' by Fritz Leiber. It appeared in [The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction, March 1962](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v022n03_1962-03_PDF/page/n39/mode/2up) and can be read at that link.

Last lines:

> One had to strain that reconstruction, though, to explain the additional freakish elements in the accident—the facts that the high-tension wire had struck not only through the bedroom window, but then through the bedroom door to catch the old man in the hall, and that the black shiny cord of the phone was wrapped like a vine twice around the old man’s right arm, as if to hold him back from escaping until the big wire had struck.

Comment: Amazing - thank you. Have always found Fritz Lieber stories stick with me (he has written some of my favourite shorts) but this one was proving elusive. Many thanks for putting me out of my misery...

Comment: I always thought that this was a very good story.